# Activate padding and salt

Tags: c++, openssl, digital-signature

I am attempting to implement function to sign files using **OpenSSL**, and I need to activate **padding** and **salt**. My signature function is as follow:

```
unsigned char * sign( EVP_PKEY * pkey, const EVP_MD * htype, char * data, int data_len, int * sig_len ) 
{ 
   EVP_MD_CTX     md_ctx; 
   unsigned char *sig = malloc( EVP_PKEY_size(pkey) ); 


   *sig_len = EVP_PKEY_size(pkey); 

   EVP_SignInit   (&md_ctx, htype); 
   EVP_SignUpdate (&md_ctx, data, data_len); 

   if (EVP_SignFinal (&md_ctx, sig, sig_len, pkey) != 1) 
   { 
      free(sig); 
      sig = 0; 
      *sig_len = 0; 

      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr); 
   } 

   return sig; 
}
```

Is there any example of how to add padding and salt? 
Does anyone have any idea that can help resolve this issue?

Comment: Also see [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: A signature doesn't require salt as input. PSS is not deterministic so it requires random values to operate, is that what you mean? Padding is performed before modular exponentiation for RSA, it's not something that you need to encode. Both the randomization and padding are performed *internally* by the signature algorithm. To me it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve, but maybe that's because of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hi Maarten,
Thanks for yout answer. I wasn't aware of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My problem X is I want to implement RSA signature with padding and salt. my solution Y is the code I posted, which implement only RSA (whitout padding and salt). As you said "padding are performed internally by the signature algorithm" so I was looking for the options to pass so the RSA is caculated with the padding and salt. I just found the solution and will post it.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution in the OpenSSL forum :

```
unsigned char * signData( EVP_PKEY * pkey, const EVP_MD * htype, char * data, int data_len, int * sig_len, int padding, int salt ) 
{
    unsigned int signature_l;
    unsigned char signature[512]; 
    int res;
    EVP_MD_CTX* verif_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create(); 
    EVP_MD_CTX* md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create(); 
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* keygen_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL); 
    /* signing */ 
    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(md_ctx, &keygen_ctx, EVP_sha512(), NULL, pkey)<1) 
        return 0;
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(keygen_ctx, padding)<1) 
        return 0; 
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_pss_saltlen(keygen_ctx, salt)<1) 
        return 0; 
    signature_l = EVP_PKEY_size(pkey); 

    if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(md_ctx, data, data_len)<1) return 0;
    if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(md_ctx, signature, &signature_l)<1) return 0; 
    /* verifying */     
    if (EVP_DigestVerifyInit(verif_ctx, &keygen_ctx, EVP_sha512(), NULL, pkey)<1) 
        return 0;
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(verif_ctx->pctx, padding)<1) 
        return 0;
    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_pss_saltlen(verif_ctx->pctx, salt)<1) 
        return 0;
    if (EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(verif_ctx, data, data_len)<1) 
        return 0;
    res = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(verif_ctx, signature, signature_l); 
    switch(res) 
    { 
    case 1:printf("sig checks out!\n"); 
        break; 
    case 0:printf("nope nope nope.\n"); break; 
    default: return 0;
    }
    return signature; 
}
```

hope this might help someone in the future !

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to verify using the same private key `pkey` as for signing.